# Tensorflow Object Detection API error with 16-bit images (PNG)

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I have an error with 16-bit images of grayscale (channel = 1). In the object_detection_tutorial file jupyter notebook I have the following error:
Value Error: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 480, 640, 1) for Tensor 'image_tensor:0', which has shape '(?, ?, ?, 3)' .

What are steps required in feeding 16-bit 1 channel images for pre trained models?

---

Error in this line:

```
def load_image_into_numpy_array(image):
(im_width, im_height) = image.size
return np.array(image.getdata()).reshape(
(im_height, im_width,1)).astype(np.uint16)
```

Answer (score 1):

The pre-trained models currently included in the [TensorFlow object detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/809fc4d/research/object_detection/README.md) all operate on 3-channel RGB images so you will not be able to use them as-is on grayscale images.

For that you'll likely have to train your own model after adjusting the model definition to operate on single channel images.